# Rounding down problem in an SSAS Tabular Cube

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, cube

So one measure from my tabular cube is a View column in my database. For a certain combination of filters, its value in my view is 51.18, while when I query the cube, it gives me 51.

Any idea where the rounding down may have come into play ? I'm not that familiar with SSAS so sorry if it's a little shaky, I'm still Learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your SSAS Model in VS, select the measure and under properties you will see a format field which you can change to decimal.